# PayPal rejects OpenSSH

Tags: java, paypal, certificate

I use PuttyGen to generate a `paypal.pem` [as described here (but save as .ossh).](http://www.linuxhelp.in/2012/04/creating-pem-key-from-ppk-key.html)

Ok, finally i configure Paypal like this:

```
PayRequest request = new PayRequest();
   ...
HashMap<String, String> configurationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
configurationMap.put("acct1.UserName", "XXX");
configurationMap.put("acct1.Password", "XXX");
configurationMap.put("acct1.CertKey", "XXX");
configurationMap.put("acct1.CertPath", "src/test/resources/PayPal09-2013.ossh");
AdaptivePaymentsService s = new AdaptivePaymentsService(configurationMap);
s.pay(request);
```

throws an `SSLConfigurationException` in the last line.

```
com.paypal.exception.SSLConfigurationException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45
    at com.paypal.core.DefaultHttpConnection.setupClientSSL(DefaultHttpConnection.java:42)
    at com.paypal.core.APIService.makeRequestUsing(APIService.java:165)
    at com.paypal.core.BaseService.call(BaseService.java:258)
    at com.paypal.svcs.services.AdaptivePaymentsService.pay(AdaptivePaymentsService.java:589)
    at com.paypal.svcs.services.AdaptivePaymentsService.pay(AdaptivePaymentsService.java:552)
          ...
Caused by: com.paypal.exception.SSLConfigurationException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45
    at com.paypal.core.SSLUtil.setupClientSSL(SSLUtil.java:129)
    at com.paypal.core.DefaultHttpConnection.setupClientSSL(DefaultHttpConnection.java:40)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 45
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:847)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1221)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at com.paypal.core.SSLUtil.p12ToKeyStore(SSLUtil.java:92)
    at com.paypal.core.SSLUtil.setupClientSSL(SSLUtil.java:115)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: SSH keys != SSL certificates.

Comment: The whole PKI system of SSH is different from X.509.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The first Google hit for the error message](http://www.advogato.org/person/johnnyb/diary.html?start=143) indicates that the notoriously uncooperative Java Crypto API requires key files to be in PKCS12 format, and that you can use OpenSSL to convert the file into PKCS12 like this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in paypal.pem -out paypal.pkcs12
```

Comment: Great! ... i need to append a Certificate (cert i downloaded from paypal.com) to `paypal.pem`. Finally openssl wont let me create a `paypal.pkcs12`-file with error "No certificate matches private key".

Comment: now, i strictly follow the todos: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/apicertificates

Comment: Thats it. Thank you anyway.